# $a,b,c > 0$ and $a+b+c=1$. Prove that $\frac{1}{a+b^2}+\frac{1}{b+c^2}+\frac{1}{c+a^2}\geqslant \frac{13}{2(1-abc)} $

Tags: inequality, contest-math

$a,b,c > 0$ and $a+b+c=1$. Prove that

$$\frac{1}{a+b^2}+\frac{1}{b+c^2}+\frac{1}{c+a^2}\geqslant \frac{13}{2(1-abc)} $$

This inequality can be solved by computer ( essentially, remove the constrain through homogenizing, clear denominator, expanding and proving positive terms). Since this mechanical strategy is very simple to do but impractical during math contest, I am looking forward to solution using classical inequalities approach.

Comment: Where did that inequality come from?

Answer (score 0):

I would not call this an answer, but perhaps could be helpful. Observe that:
\begin{align*}
(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)&=\color{red}{1-a-b-c}+ab+ac+bc-abc\\
&=ab+ac+bc-abc \\
&=\frac{(a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{2}-abc \\
&=\frac{1-(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{2}-abc \\
&=1-abc-\frac{1+a^2+b^2+c^2}{2} \\
&=1-abc-\frac{a+b+c+a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}.
\end{align*}
Thus, $$a+b+c+a^2+b^2+c^2=2[(1-abc)-(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)].$$
By Cauchy Schwartz inequality, $$(a+b+c+a^2+b^2+c^2)\left(\frac{1}{a+b^2}+\frac{1}{b+c^2}+\frac{1}{c+a^2}\right)\geq3^2=9.$$
As a result, $$\frac{1}{a+b^2}+\frac{1}{b+c^2}+\frac{1}{c+a^2}\geq\frac{9}{2[(1-abc)-(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)]}.$$
If we can show $$\frac{9}{2[(1-abc)-(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)]}\geq\frac{13}{2(1-abc)},$$ then we are done. Suppose this is true. It gives $$13[(1-abc)-(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)]\leq 9(1-abc),$$ or equivalently, $$(1-abc)\leq\frac{13}{4}(1-a)(1-b)(1-c).$$
If this inequality is true under the constraint $a+b+c=1$ and $a,b,c>0$, then we are done. I checked that the equality precisely holds when $a=b=c=1/3$. Hope anyone can finish it.

Comment: That last inequality doesn't hold for $a=b=\frac{1}{4}, c = \frac{1}{2}$. The LHS would be $\frac{124}{128}$, while the RHS would be $\frac{117}{128}$

Comment: @VarunVejalla Thanks. Then this method will not go... :(

Comment: @BernardPan although your approach has reached a dead end i must say its pretty creative

Comment: The method reached a dead end because of the application of CS. IE the inequality $ 9 /  ( \sum a + b^2 ) >= 13/ 2 ( 1- abc) $ isn't true. The re-write of $1-abc$ hasn't quite been used as yet.